# Fluid layout with fixed width image, preventing overlapping

Tags: css

the website is available to inspect here - http://manchestergardeningservices.co.uk/fluid/

I have created a fluid layout and have placed a 600 pixel wide image into the `content` column, but when I resize the window, so that the `content` column is less than 600 pixels wide, the result is that the image is overlapping with the sidebar as shown below.

I thought that adding the `min-width` property to `div id ="content"` would possibly be a way to resolve the issue, but if this property is added the green sidebar will sit underneath the `div id ="content"` when the web page is reduced in size.

```
#content {
    min-width: 600px;
    float:left;
    width:70%;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add width:100% to image

```
<img src="bane.jpg" alt="bane" style="width: 100%;">
```

and remove min-width: 600px; from content